# How to set row id for GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My Gridview in my .aspx page looks like:

```
<asp:GridView ...>

<headerstyle ... />
<RowStyle .... />
<Columns>

  <asp:TemplateField ...>
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("Name") %>
    </itemTemplate>
  </asp:TEmplateField>

</Columns>


</asp:GridView>
```

I want to set the row ID so I can use jquery to get access to the row in a accurate manner.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the row ID inside the RowDataBound event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var row = e.Row;
        row.Attributes["id"] = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```